# Will my incognito tabs restore after I shutdown?

Tags: private-browsing

I always ask personal questions in incognito so nobody will see them. But this time I had to shut down my laptop and couldn't close the tabs due to my sibling needing to use it. If they log in to my laptop, will they see the incognito tabs pop up?

Comment: No, incognito sessions cannot be restored once closed. You can confirm this is the case by opening a incognito session

Answer (score 2):

An incognito browser window should close all tabs and remove cookies upon closing the window, which will happen if you reboot or shutdown the computer.

Whether or not this happens is hard to answer given that you did not specify which browser you are actually using.

The browsers that are used most often, Chrome, Edge and Firefox all do this. Most other browsers do too, but there may be a browser out there where they have an option to keep the incognito session alive and use it more like a guest account.

It is therefor best to just test it. Run an experiment where you have an incognito window running alongside a normal window, have some tabs open and then reboot/shutdown your pc, then start it up and then start your browser to see what remained.